# Has anyone parsed Wiktionary?

Tags: python, web-services, dictionary, wiktionary

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org) is a wiki dictionary that covers many languages. It even has translations. I would be interested in parsing it and playing with the data, has anyone does anything like this before? Is there any library I can use? (Preferably Python.)

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Parsing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wiktionary runs on MediaWiki, which [has an API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

One of the subpages for the API documentation is [Client code, which lists some Python libraries](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python).

Answer (score 23):

I had at one time downloaded a wiktionary dump, trying to gather together words and definitions for slavic languages.  I approached it using elementtree to go thru the xml file that is the dump.  I would avoid trying to scrape or crawl the site, and just download the xml dump that wikimedia provides for wiktionary. Go to the [wikimedia downloads](http://download.wikimedia.org/), look for the english wiktionary dumps ([enwiktionary](http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/)) and go to the most recent dump.  You'll probably want the pages-articles.xml.bz2 file, which is just the article content, no history or comments.  Parse this with whatever xml processing libraries you prefer in python.  I personally prefer elementtree.  Good luck.

Comment: How did you use elementtree? As far as I can see, most of the data is not xml tagged, ie, you get everything under <text>: <text xml:space="preserve">==English== ===Etymology 1=== {{rfe}} ====Pronunciation==== * {{enPR|fēt}}, {{IPA|/fiːt/|lang=en}} * {{audio|en-us-feet.ogg|Audio (US)|lang=en}} * {{rhymes|iːt|lang=en}} * {{homophones|lang=en|feat}} ====Noun==== {{en-plural noun}}

Answer (score 15):

[wordnik](http://wordnik.com) has done a good job parsing-out definitions, etc
and they have a [great api](http://api.wordnik.com)

like the others have mentioned, wiktionary is a formatting-disaster, and was not built to be computer-readable

Comment: Thanks, wordnik works perfectly for me. I have a [thin Python client](https://github.com/jabbalaci/jabbapylib/blob/master/jabbapylib/dictionary/wordnik.py) for getting definitions and examples for a word.

Comment: Do you recognize that the dump from wikimedia is intentionally partial? In fact, it is also maliciously partial in that the dump misses very basic and often used word while containing a lot of words that many of us don't even know exist.

Comment: @InformedA Link for "intentionally partial", please. If you found some page which is present on the wiki but not in the dumps, have you [reported the bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/?projects=Dumps-Generation)?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, many people parsed Wiktionary. You can usually find past experiences in the [Wiktionary-l mailing list archives](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wiktionary-l/).

A project not mentioned by other answers is DBPedia's [Wiktionary RDF extraction](http://dbpedia.org/wiktionary-rdf-extraction).

Dozens other research projects parsed Wiktionary: you can find some examples in a recent [Wiktionary special](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Newsletter/2015/September#Wiktionary_special) and in [other issues](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=wiktionary&prefix=Research%3ANewsletter%2F20&fulltext=Search+past+issues&fulltext=Search) of the Wikimedia research newsletter.

[Recently](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T119235) someone also made an [English Wiktionary REST API](https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Page_content/get_page_definition_term) which includes an unspecified subset of the Wiktionary data; future plans for the thing are not known yet.

Answer (score 9):

I had a crack at parsing the german wiktionary.  I ended up writing it off as too difficult, but I put my (not at all tidied up) code up at https://github.com/benreynwar/wiktionary-parser before I gave up.  Although there are conventions used by the editors they are not enforced by anything other than peer oversight.  The diversity of templates used along with all the typos in the pages makes the parsing quite challenging.

I think the problem is that they've used the same system as for wiktionary which is great for ease of use by the editors, but is not appropriate for the much more structured content of wiktionary. It's a shame because if wiktionary could be easily parsed it would be a hugely useful resource.

Comment: Just saw this when looking at other slashdot wiktionary questions.  It might be useful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquitous_Knowledge_Processing_Lab#Wiktionary_API

Comment: This project is now hosted at https://github.com/benreynwar/wiktionary-parser.
It remains neglected.

Answer (score 4):

I just made a word list from the German dump like that:

```
bzcat pages-articles.xml.bz2 | grep '<title>[^[:space:][:punct:]]*</title>' | sed 's:.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*:\1:' > words
```

Comment: I think the question was about parsing the wiki content, not the XML.

Answer (score 4):

You are welcome to play with the MySQL parsed Wiktionary database.
There are two databases (English Wiktionary and Russian Wiktionary) created by the parser written in Java: [http://wikokit.googlecode.com](https://code.google.com/p/wikokit/)

If you like PHP, then you are welcome to play with [piwidict](https://github.com/componavt/piwidict) - PHP API to this machine-readable Wiktionary [2](https://github.com/componavt/piwidict)

Comment: This may be the most hopeful option of all written thus far. +1

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [dbnary](http://kaiko.getalp.org/about-dbnary/) project, not python but interesting.
Claims support parsing for 21 languages and it powers [wikdict](http://www.wikdict.com/).

Comment: WikDict also provide downloads of translation data which has been further processed to make it easier to use. See http://www.wikdict.com/page/about .

Answer (score 1):

There is also [JWKTL](https://code.google.com/p/jwktl/) which does a good job at parsing and extracting structured data from wiktionary. It is written in Java and has support for the English, German and Russian editions.

Comment: I think it doesn't support French, but German

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how thoroughly you need to parse it. If you just need to get all contents of a word in a language (definition, etymology, pronunciation, conjugation, etc.) then it's pretty easy. I had done this before, although [in Java using jsoup](https://github.com/chinhodado/fr_dict/blob/master/src/chin/com/frdict/SearchWordAsyncTask.java)

However, if you need to parse it down to different components of the content (e.g. just getting the definitions of a word), then it will be much more challenging. A Wiktionary entry for a word in a language has no pre-defined template, so a header can be anything from `<h3>` to `<h6>`, the order of the sections may be jumbled, they can be repetitive, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a primitive [parser for the German Wiktionary dump](https://github.com/publishing-systems/clients/tree/master/org.wiktionary/wiktionary_dump_to_xml_1) in Java that only extracts nouns and their articles, plus their Arabic translation, without any dependencies. Execution takes a long time, so be warned. If there’s interest/need to parse more or other data, please tell me, I might look into it as time permits.