# Dictionary of words and their translation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dictionary

Consider the simple following HTML code:

```
<input id="dict_field" type="text"/>
<button id="translate_btn" type="button" class="btn">translate</button>
```

The user inputs something and clicking the button triggers a function that returns a translation.

And the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#translate_btn').click(function(){
    var word = $('#dict_field').val();
    var translation = "";
    translation = translate(word (, dictionary?));
    // For simplicity for now just display the result in the same input field
    $('#dict_field').val(translation)
  });

});

// pseudo code. How to implement this and build the dictionary I need?

function translate(word (, dictionary?)){
  if word in dictionary.keys() -> return dictionary[word]
  else return "no such word in dict"
}
```

Given the following:

1. The translation needs only to be one way (key to value).
2. The dictionary is custom made (meaning I have to build it, I cannot count on external API such as Google's).
3. I estimate the size of the dictionary keys could be of the order of thousands, say between 1 and 5000.
4. Not sure if related but eventually I'd like the translation to happen in real time (as soon as the user finishes the input without need of a button click). This for now is secondary.

What is a good way, "objectively", to build a map/dictionary {key:value} to implement a translation function/API? Any detail can be considered, such as speed, scalability, cost etc., keeping in view my above requirements.

I've little experience with this kind of things, but I have some thoughts, such as:

1. Use a very long js file containing the dictionary (might not be a good idea)
2. Store everything in a text file and read from there
3. Look at some database (but won't that be overkill?)

Appreciate valuable suggestions. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The dictionary would contain words only? And do you plan to add more description, helping material, links etc. along with translation?

Comment: Good point. For now I think  words only should be fine (eg just a translate('foo') = 'bar'). Obviously the more flexible the better I guess should I in the future decide to add more to it.

Comment: Just use a JSON file with whatever structure suits you.

Comment: Is the question still too broad after the kind edit by @TalhaAwan?

Comment: @Tommy, I don't know how and when on hold is removed after edit. I think the answer to the question will still be opinion based but it's really a good question. I wanted to answer that but I can't now. Maybe try another well-directed question. If you do so, tag me here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a text file, e.g. CSV.

```
foo,bar
baz,quux
```

Then fetch it with ajax, and split it. You can optimize this, but not likely required.

```
var dict = text
  .split('\n')
  .map(function(x) { return x.split(',') })
  .reduce(function(acc, pair) { acc[pair[0]] = pair[1]; return acc }, {});
```

Then `dict['bar'] === 'quux'`.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. So I can fetch the dict right, but dict[key] returns undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: Got it! I think it should be acc[pair[0]] = pair[1].

Comment: @Tommy yep, my mistake, updated.

Comment: No worries, it's good it actually forced me to understand what I was doing. :) one thing, forgive the silly question but what does "acc" stand for?

Comment: @Tommy Accumulator

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object `{"key":"value"}` or an array of arrays `[["key", "value"]]` or an array or array of objects `[{"key":"value0"}, {"key":"value1"}]`; where the latter two would allow more than one definition for the same word, to handle equivocal languages; and the ability to include metadata relating to the word or term within the array or object, for example an [audio representation of the spoken word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser).