# Python load 2GB of text file to memory

Tags: python, memory, text-files

In Python 2.7, when I load all data from a text file of 2.5GB into memory for quicker processing like this:

```
>>> f = open('dump.xml','r')
>>> dump = f.read()
```

I got the following error:

```
Python(62813) malloc: *** mmap(size=140521659486208) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Why did Python try to allocate `140521659486208` bytes memory for `2563749237` bytes data? How do I fix the code to make it loads all the bytes?

I'm having around 3GB RAM free. The file is a Wiktionary xml dump.

Comment: Why don't you parse the XML linearly without loading the source into memory first?

Comment: I tried it and it took me very long. And since I have lots of RAM, I want to load everything into RAM to make it faster.

Comment: I got 8GB RAM on my Mac Pro, I think it's 64bit

Comment: Have you tried invoking mmap manually?

Comment: Wow. 128 Terabytes? That's ambitious of `malloc()`.

Comment: I'm very new to Python. Now I'm reading on that. What puzzled me the most was why would Python want to allocate like 50K bytes memory per byte data? What kind of data structure behind the f.read() line is that?

Comment: I don't think that reading the XML source into memory to parse it afterwards will speed up anything.  Parse it while reading it.  That's faster.

Comment: BTW, use a SAX parser instead of a DOM parser.  Otherwise you will again need huge amounts of RAM.

Comment: @Alfe I have tried XML parsing by accumulating the lines until a complete article entry, it took me forever. So I changed to this solution to use regex finditer() to linearly match the pattern and extract the interested data instead. Now it only took me more than a minute.

Comment: I suggest using xml ElementTree over using SAX. No one but you will like your regex solution.

Comment: [Others on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364279/has-anyone-parsed-wiktionary) have looked at this very XML file to parse. You may want to look at that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of those links. I was just trying to separate the page title and content from the dump for doing experiments later. ElementTree was the one that took a long time before I switching over to the regex solution. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html), you'll be able to load the entire file into memory immediately.

```
import mmap

with open('dump.xml', 'rb') as f:
  # Size 0 will read the ENTIRE file into memory!
  m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ) #File is open read-only

  # Proceed with your code here -- note the file is already in memory
  # so "readine" here will be as fast as could be
  data = m.readline()
  while data:
    # Do stuff
    data = m.readline()
```

Comment: I got `mmap.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied` for the line with `m = mmap.mmap(..)`, how do i fix it?

Comment: @pckben That's because the file is open in read-only mode and mmap will try to map read-write: add `prot=mmap.PROT_READ` in your `mmap.mmap` call, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Nice answer if you really have to read the contents of a file completely.  In this case I don't think that this is the best solution for pckben's situation.

Comment: mmap is memory mapping of a file.  Accessing the memory at the allocated place will access the file instead.  Whether the OS buffers the whole file beforehand or only on access, is part of the configuration ;-)

Comment: @pckben Using `open('myfile', 'rb')` opens the file in read-only mode, but `mmap` will try to map it read-write, which causes the error.

Answer (score -1):

Based on some quick googling, I came across [this forum post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/712612) that seems to address the issue that you appear to be having. Assuming that you are running Mac or Linux based on the error code, you may try implementing garbage collection with `gc.enable()` or `gc.collect()` as suggested in the forum post.

Comment: my code is only 2 lines as given for loading data into the memory, there's no other living object for garbage collection.