# Class attribute is not included in bs4 object

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this [site](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/opiera%C4%87#opiera%C4%87(j%C4%99zyk_polski)) and I am using the `requests` library and `BeautifulSoup`. So here's the deal folks, I simply do a `requests.get()` and convert its `.content` to a `bs4` object. (My parser is `"html5lib"`)

Now before that as you can see in the image here there is a `class` attribute on this tag.
You can do an inspect element on the site by yourself to see what I am talking about. You can visit the [site](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/opiera%C4%87#opiera%C4%87(j%C4%99zyk_polski)) and right click on the boxed word and inspect element.

[image: img1]

Now when I get the `.content` of it and convert it to a bs4 object and printout the `soup` variable, as you can see the `<p>` tag I am pointing out in the arrows **does not have** the `class` attribute anymore, it is just simple a `<p>`. Check it out here, I already tried doing a find on sublime text the class value itself but there are no results, so this would mean that the `class` attribute indeed is **NOT INCLUDED**.

(I cannot put here the whole value of soup since it is too long, I suggest you print it out too)

You might be wondering why do I need the `class` attribute? I need it to gather the relevant data based on that class, I need it to be SPECIFICALLY based on that class since I cannot just `.find()` a `p` tag since there are many cases that there would be other `p` tags but they are not the data I am trying to get, so I am just being precise.

[image: img2]

Also here is the simple code I made, take note also that I already have tried putting a User-Agent on it since I've searched also to try and fake like a browser, but still no luck :( can someone help me and enlighten me also on why this is happening? Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = "opierać"

url = f"https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/{word}#{word}_(j%C4%99zyk_polski)"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print("Status code: ",r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html5lib")
print(soup)
```

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364279/has-anyone-parsed-wiktionary

Comment: Thanks but the API doesn't seem to have the task to gather data from a particular page like that one I have provided... I think it seems different :(

Comment: Would help if this was in English. I don't get it. You want `p` elements from page which have no `class` , but you want `class`?

Comment: It seems like the classes of that tag ```<p>``` are being generated by JavaScript code so you wont be able to get it using **BeautifouSoup** neither **requests**, instead you could use **Selenium**. Or try to take that info without relying on the class.

Comment: we don't need it to be in english cause I also don't know how to speak polish :D 

Yeess I am wondering the same thing.. it could be because of javascript.. is there a way to have it? as you can see on the image the class attribute is there but when I get it using requests and parse it ... the class attribute is gone.

Comment: as @Gealber said, you could use selenium to open it and then pass the code to beautifulsoup, also i think its not necessary to have headers=headers in line 8

Comment: Yuup I've already thought of that but to be honest I can't have another third party program in it since I'll be using chromedriver.exe, but thanks anyways! I'll look onto it if I really have to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gealber, I would also recommend [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to perform your task.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = "opierać"
url = f"https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/{word}#{word}_(j%C4%99zyk_polski)"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib")
p = soup.find('p', class_='lang-pl fldt-znaczenia')
print(p)
driver.close()
```

Used an implicit wait for fully load of website ([More about selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)):

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

**Output**

```
<p class="lang-pl fldt-znaczenia"><i class="lang-pl fldt-znaczenia">czasownik przechodni niedokonany</i> (<link class="lang-pl fldt-znaczenia" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r6240524" rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style"/><span class="short-container lang-pl fldt-znaczenia"><a class="mw-redirect lang-pl fldt-znaczenia" href="/wiki/Aneks:Skr%C3%B3ty_u%C5%BCywane_w_Wikis%C5%82owniku#D" title="Aneks:Skróty używane w Wikisłowniku"><span class="short-wrapper lang-pl fldt-znaczenia" data-expanded="aspekt dokonany" title="aspekt dokonany"><span class="short-content lang-pl fldt-znaczenia">dk.</span></span></a></span> <a class="lang-pl fldt-znaczenia" href="/wiki/opra%C4%87#pl" title="oprać">oprać</a>)
</p>
```

You can also go for all of the `p` tags with that special `class` and loop through:

```
soup.find_all('p', class_='lang-pl fldt-znaczenia')
```

Comment: Thanks! actually my last choice to do this is using Selenium just like what you have done... but I'll still do more research and other ways I could think of... since I am trying to do this without any other 3rd party software.

Comment: I'll check this once I decide to do selenium.

Comment: I like the answer of @QHarr! but for the question I am referring I think the best way is to have it on selenium.. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can select on the basis the `p` tag you want [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) a child `i` tag (requires bs4.7.1+) and is the first to match this pattern.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(requests.get('https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/opiera%C4%87#opiera%C4%87(j%C4%99zyk_polski').content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('p:has(i)').text)
```

Comment: Wooow! Thank you! I did not know that this is possible! this is a good way to make my code precise too.... may I ask can I put anything I mean anything inside the `has`? for example for `<label>` tag I could put `p:has(label)` ? Thanks

Comment: This one I consider to be a checked answer too!

Comment: But there could only be one answer... but this I consider to be `another` alternative solution for my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @QHarr Great solution to work without any `id, name or class` attributes - I also take a closer look.

Comment: @StackOffended Yes you can put label inside. You can nest css selectors inside :has

Comment: Thanks! So I can put any possible tag I want there? Great!